# PhD defence announcement

Tags: phd, communication, defense, announcements

What information should contain a (A4-sized, landscape-oriented) poster announcing a PhD defence? What idioms, jargon or style is usually used? Could you provide some models or examples?

Comment: In the vein of Stack Overflow, what do you have so far? Feel free to use `The History of Potato Cultivation by John Doe` as an example if you need one. As it stands, you could literally be asking for "Who/what/when/where/why/how?" or you could already have all of that but need a blurb to fill in.

Comment: Will there be food?

Comment: @AustinHenley **Pizza will be provided.** #fullhouse

Comment: @AustinHenley et al., there won't be any food. As we say in my region, there will be neither chips, nor peanuts in shell nor lupins (which are typical snacks in any rustic lunch-brunch; see #laculturadelalmuerzo in the Internet).

Comment: Including [this xkcd inforgraphic](https://xkcd.com/1403/) should get some people's attentions...

Comment: @recursion.ninja ha ha, I knew that one... 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example, from my PhD institution, seems to be pretty typical.  As you can see it's quite basic.  I don't think there's really a need to include much more information than this.  The only thing I might add is a short abstract.

[image]

Comment: A friend of mine helped me to design the poster announcing my PhD defence. Here you can have a look at it: http://personales.upv.es/vigibos/docs/phd_thesis/PhD_defence_announcement_poster_by_Ramon_Rosello_Design.jpg